# Vue js child and parent components

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

How to understand child and parent components? Where is the child or parent? In documentation i did not founded this desription. Please help.

In example below i see only one component whithout parent or child. Only one. This is "my-component". Waiting for the answer.Thanks.

```
Vue.component("my-component", {
    template: `<li> Hello </li>`
})

new Vue({
    el: "#app"
})

<div id="app">
    <my-component> </my-component>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Vue - #app is the parent and the component - my-component is child. 
The component which is inside is a child, its pretty obvious